# Azure Bot: How to check if or extract the LUIS 'entity' present in the response to prompt for user input?

Tags: node.js, azure, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

```
        .matches('Note.Create', [(session, args, next) => {
            // Resolve and store any Note.Title entity passed from LUIS.
            var intent = args.intent;
            var title = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(intent.entities, 'Note.Title');

            var note = session.dialogData.note = {
              title: title ? title.entity : null,
            };

            // Prompt for title
            if (!note.title) {
                builder.Prompts.text(session, 'What would you like to call your note?');
            } else {
                next();
            }
        },
 (session, results) => {
        var note = session.dialogData.note;
        if (results.response) {
            note.text = results.response;
        }
    .
    .
    .
        }])
```

In the above code, when the user asks `What would you like to call your note?`. The responses from the user can be like `My Note Title` or `i would like call my note **My note Title**` or `Let us call it **My Note Title**`.

So the question is how to extract/get only `My Note Title` out of the response to the `Prompts`.

It is currently storing the whole response in  `note.text = results.response;`